# Multi step registration - save on last step

Tags: 7, users, forms

I'm using the module [Multi-Step Registration](https://www.drupal.org/project/step) module. The problem is that the user is saved after clicking the continue button on the first step. So when a user quits after 3 steps the user is saved already ... (but the registration process isn't completed).

Does anyone have an idea how I could the save the user on the last step or a workaround to fix this?

Comment: This module have only dev version, so answers to your question would probably outdate quickly. But it is the way module is designed (to make "Each step of the wizard can (...) expose one ore more Profile2 types" possible). You need to file a feature request if you want to have it any other way.

Answer (score 0):

You could consider one of two modules that force users to complete their profile if they've dropped off halfway thorough, but still created the account:

[Complete Profile](http://drupal.org/project/complete_profile) or Profile Fields Force Filling

Or, [roll your own form using ctools](http://www.grasmash.com/article/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7-using-ctools).